# how to define callback for my program in android Studio?

Tags: android, callback

I want to define callback for a Notebook program that way after note saved in EditActivity,in Main Activity Update list of notes,But This does not happen.

**EditActivity:**

```
public interface OnClickDoneListener{
    void onClickDone();
}

public void setOnClickDoneListener(OnClickDoneListener onClickDoneListener){
    this.onClickDoneListener=onClickDoneListener;
}
btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (extras != null) {
                myDatabase.updateRow(id, txtTitle.getText().toString(), txtDesc.getText().toString());
                NoteModel noteModel = new NoteModel();
                noteModel.setTitle(txtTitle.getText().toString());
                noteModel.setDesc(txtDesc.getText().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(EditActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                onClickDoneListener.onClickDone();
            } else {
                Done();
            }

        }
    });
```

Main Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setupViews();

    getDataFromDB();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(MainActivity.this,dataList));
    noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(MainActivity.this,dataList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
    fabAdd = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab_main_add) ;

    EditActivity editActivity = new EditActivity();
    editActivity.setOnClickDoneListener(new EditActivity.OnClickDoneListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickDone() {
            noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

please help me.

My English is poor,sorry for it.

Answer (score 0):

You want your data to be updated when the MainActivity is shown, right ?

You just have to call your `getDataFromDB` part in `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

```
EditActivity editActivity = new EditActivity();
editActivity.setOnClickDoneListener(new EditActivity.OnClickDoneListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClickDone() {
        noteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

What you are doing here is setting the value of OnClickDoneListener in a new instance of EditActivity that you will never use. Because when you use new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class) to start the EditActivity it will create a new instance of EditActivity and your interface would be null.

I suggest you use android's Broadcast Receiver instead of a callback in this case. All you have to do is:

- In MainActivity: You will need to instantiate a broadcast receiver. You need to register it onCreate or onStart and unregister it onStop or onDestory.
- In EditAcitivity: You send a broadcast whenever you want to notify your MainActivity to update the list.

Check out this example:
https://riptutorial.com/android/example/18305/communicate-two-activities-through-custom-broadcast-receiver